# How to play Video TS folder in VLC or convert it to MP4

Tags: video, mp4, conversion, vlc

I am trying to play a DVD by copying the contents (a Video TS and a Jacket_P folder) to my computer. I copied the Video_TS and Jacket_P folders from a DVD to my computer. The Video_TS folder has the VOB, IFO and BUP files and the Jacket_P folder has 3 .MP2 files. I opened the Video TS folder in VLC but the video does not play. I have also tried using software like Winx DVD Ripper but I get an error message with error code 1 saying that it is unable to convert the files. Does anyone know how to fix this issue, either by converting the DVD to MP4 or playing it in VLC?

Answer (score 1):

Video data should be in `*.vob` files. You need to `copy` almost all existing `*.vob` files into one (almost all because `VTS_01_0.VOB` has DVD menu data so you can skip it). Here is an example for five existing `*.vod` files:

```
copy /b VTS_01_1.VOB + VTS_01_2.VOB + VTS_01_3.VOB + VTS_01_4.VOB + VTS_01_5.VOB output.vob
```

Now you can convert `output.vob` file to mp4 format with [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html):

```
ffmpeg -i output.vob -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4
```